# react state bind from child to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new to reactJS

I have an JSON array which consists of task. I have rendered the the array to 2 ul list. One has completed tasks and the other has uncompleted tasks. If i click on the task the status is changing but it is not updated in other element. However if I enter some text in the input state is set to other elements. Why the state is not set immediately when I click on task?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="todo">
</div>
<script type="text/jsx">
    var TodoList = React.createClass({
        clickHandle: function(index) {
            this.props.items[index].completed=!this.props.items[index].completed;
            console.log(this.props);
            this.setState({items: this.props.items});
        },
        render: function() {
          var createItem = function(itemText, index) {
            if(itemText.completed===this.props.completed)
                return <li key={index} onClick={this.clickHandle.bind(this,index)}>{itemText.text}</li>;
          };
          return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem, this)}</ul>;
        }
      });
      var TodoApp = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {items: [{"text":"1true","completed":true},{"text":"2true","completed":true},{"text":"1false","completed":false}], text: ''};
        },
        onChange: function(e) {
          this.setState({text: e.target.value});
        },
        handleSubmit: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if(this.state.text!=''){
              this.state.items.push({"text":this.state.text,"completed":false});
              var nextText = '';
              this.setState({items:this.state.items,text: nextText});
          }
          else{
            alert("Enter some text!");
          }
        },
        render: function() {
          return (
            <div>
              <h3>TODO</h3>
              <TodoList items={this.state.items} completed={false}/>
              <TodoList items={this.state.items} completed={true}/>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} />
                <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      React.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('todo'));

</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqqcg1sa/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the parent component, TodoApp which renders the two lists does not know that something has changed in one of the them. For this the child component should notify the parent component about it.

Add a onStatusUpdate attribute to TodoList like this

```
<TodoList items={this.state.items} completed={false} onStatusUpdate={this.update}/>
```

This is how the update method can be defined

```
update: function(items){
  this.setState({items: items});
}
```

In the click handler of child component do something like this

```
clickHandle: function(index {
  this.props.items[index].completed=!this.props.items[index].completed;
  this.props.onStatusUpdate(this.props.items); // <-- this triggers the onStatusUpdate attribute defined in TodoList component
},
```

Here is an updated demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aqqcg1sa/2/`**

Comment: what is the use of `this.props.onStatusUpdate(this.props.items);` in clickHandle?

Comment: it will trigger the `onStatusUpdate` attribute defined in `<TodoList />` Component. The child component will just change the status of the selected item and send the updated array to parent component. The parent component will take the updated list and render again